# error in nnet: “initial value in 'vmmin' is not finite”

Tags: r, neural-network, nnet

I'm attempting to run a neural network model for the first time using nnet in r. When I supply a range of values to be given to the "size" argument, I get the following error:

```
Error in nnet.default(x, y, w, entropy = TRUE, ...) :
  initial value in 'vmmin' is not finite
```

However when I pass a single value to the "size" argument, the function works without any problem. Why is this error occurring and how can I get around it?

Here is a reproducible example:

```
Var1 <- rnorm(100, 1, 2)
Var2 <- rnorm(100, 1, 2)
Var3 <- rnorm(100, 1, 2)
Var4 <- rnorm(100, 1, 2)
Var5 <- as.factor(runif(100)<=.50)
outcome <- as.factor(runif(100)<=.90)
data <- data.frame(outcome, Var1, Var2, Var3, Var4, Var5)
neural_net <- nnet(outcome ~ ., data = data, decay=5e-4, maxit=200, size = seq(from = 2, to = 30, by = 1))
```

And this is my R version info:

```
> version
           _                           
platform       x86_64-w64-mingw32          
arch           x86_64                      
os             mingw32                     
system         x86_64, mingw32             
status                                     
major          3                           
minor          4.0                         
year           2017                        
month          04                          
day            21                          
svn rev        72570                       
language       R                           
version.string R version 3.4.0 (2017-04-21)
nickname       You Stupid Darkness
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`nnet` only fits single-hidden-layer neural networks, so `size` (the number of neurons in the hidden layer) can only be a scalar.

The nnet package is very obsolete now. It dates to the 1990s, before all the current advances in deep learning were made. Consider using a more modern package if you want to learn about neural nets in R, like RStudio's [tensorflow](https://github.com/rstudio/tensorflow) or Microsoft R's [MicrosoftML](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/r-server/r-reference/microsoftml/microsoftml-package). The latter is actually a toolkit of machine learning algorithms including random forests, boosted trees, and others in addition to NNs.